# Unofficial webapp office is no longer available

Tags: 20.04, microsoft-office

I tried installing [unofficial webapp office](https://github.com/sirredbeard/unofficial-webapp-office) but it is no longer available in the snap store https://snapcraft.io/search?q=unofficial-webapp.

Is there another way to install it? I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can create desktop shortcuts for any website in Firefox/Chrom(ium). Simply create some for Office webapps. Then copy those .desktop files to the hidden folder `.local/share/applications` and you can find them in the menus.

Comment: but that would open them in the same browser as everything else. I don't want the search bar and it should open in its separate window everytime. I have also tried an application (I forgot its name), which creates apps out of websites, but every time I open a word document it opens a new window and by closing the old one the program closes entirely.

Answer (score 3):

There is an alternative to unofficial webapp office. It's called Office365WebDesktop and you can find it in Ubuntu Software

[image: screenshot]

Alternatively, open a terminal and enter

```
sudo snap install office365webdesktop --beta
```

Comment: Quite good, even though it's just a wrapper for the browser, with the webapp limitations.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Google Docs are now pretty awesome with `.doc` editing. Google doesn't convert file to their format but actually edits original one. You do it with browser on any computer / mobile. They are working hard on it to support M$ Office formats on Chromebooks.

Just add your Word document to Google Drive and double click on it.